# How can I nest this conditional statement? in Java

Tags: java

I am a Java student and I am having trouble with nesting the conditional statement of this program

> Exercise CozaLozaWoza (Loop & Condition): Write a program called
>   CozaLozaWoza which prints the numbers 1 to 110, 11 numbers per line.
>   The program shall print "Coza" in place of the numbers which are
>   multiples of 3, "Loza" for multiples of 5, "Woza" for multiples of 7,
>   "CozaLoza" for multiples of 3 and 5, and so on. The output shall look
>   like:

```
1 2 Coza 4 Loza Coza Woza 8 Coza Loza 11 
Coza 13 Woza CozaLoza 16 17 Coza 19 Loza CozaWoza 22 
23 Coza Loza 26 Coza Woza 29 CozaLoza 31 32 Coza
......
```

I manage to do this

```
public class CozaLozaWoza {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    for (int x = 1; x <= 110; x +=1) {
        if (x % 3 == 0) {
            System.out.print(" Coza");
        }else if (x % 5 == 0) {
            System.out.print(" Loza");
        }else if (x % 7 == 0) {
            System.out.print(" Woza");
        }else if (x % 3 != 0 && x % 5 != 0 && x % 7 != 0) {
            System.out.print(" " + x);
        }


        if (x % 11 == 0) {
            System.out.println();
        }


    }
}
```

}

I can't merge the last if statement, can anyone help me? thank you

Comment: Are you sure you need nesting?

Answer (score 2):

The if statements should be independent of each other, since more than one statement can be true for the same number (for example `"CozaLoza" for multiples of 3 and 5`).

```
for (int x = 1; x <= 110; x +=1) {
    boolean regular = true;
    System.out.print (" ");
    if (x % 3 == 0) {
        System.out.print("Coza");
        regular = false;
    }
    if (x % 5 == 0) {
        System.out.print("Loza");
        regular = false;
    }
    if (x % 7 == 0) {
        System.out.print("Woza");
        regular = false;
    }
    if (regular) {
        System.out.print(x);
    }
    if (x % 11 == 0) {
        System.out.println();
    }
}
```

Comment: Thats my original code, but the exercise ask to nest it
TRY: Modify the program to use nested-if (if ... else if ... else if ... else) instead.

Comment: @ahmadaziz That would make your code uglier. You'll have to test first if the number is divisible by 3*5*7, then by 5*7, then by 3*7, then by 3*5, then by 7, then by 5 and finally by 3. And that wouldn't account for the newline condition (if you want to include that in the same if...else if... you'll need to test if the number is divisible by 77,55,33 and 11 too).

Answer (score 0):

```
   package homePrac;

public class LOZAMOZACOZA 
{
    public static void main (String []args)
    {
        int max = 110;
        for (int i=1; i<=max; i++)
        {
            if (i%3==0)
                System.out.print("Coza");
            else if (i%5==0)
                System.out.print ("Woza");
            else if (i%7==0)
                System.out.print("CozaLoza");
            else if (i%3!=0 || i%5!=0 || i%7!=0)
                System.out.print(i);
            if(i%11==0)
                System.out.println("");
        }
    }
}
```